# $http and ng-href scope propagation

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html code:

```
<a ng-href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,{{dump}}" download="dump.json">dump.json</a>
```

And then the following js code:

```
$http.get('/something').success(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});

$scope.dump = $scope.data;
```

The whole app works, tables are populated with data from `$scope.data`, but the `<a ng-gref="data:..." />` does not. Thge resulting url is just `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,`. But if I set `$scope.dump = {hello: true}`, it works. So, why is the change not propagated to `ng-href`?

EDIT: `$scope.dump = function() {return "Hello";}` also doesn't work, and I think it should.

Comment: you can directly map the data like this $scope.dump=data;

Comment: I can't. `data` is not defined before http success is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the `success` function is *asynchronous* so, although it *appears before* the `$scope.dump = $scope.data` statement, it actually *runs after* - when the HTTP call returns. Therefore `$scope.dump` is set to `undefined`.

As it is, `$scope.dump` is redundant, just use:

```
<a ng-href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,{{data}}" download="dump.json">dump.json</a>
```

Otherwise, set `$scope.dump` in the `$http.success` function.